# Hibernate query to remove leading zeros

Tags: hibernate

I want to do :

```
 select * from accounts where account_number = '234567'
```

User can enter on the GUI as account number = '234567' but database column could have the value of '0000234567' . Still it should match.

Can this SQL query work ?

```
select * from accounts a where 
(:accountNumber LIKE (TRIM(REPLACE((a.account_number), '0', '%'))))
```

Comment: Why do you ask us if the query can work, instead of just testing if it works?

Comment: You  can do something like `select * from accounts where account_number = '0000234567' * 1` instead of `replace`.

Comment: thanks for your response. my query does not work. account_number is a varchar. so i dont think i can multiply it by 1. Also, I am looking for a HQL query.

Comment: select ltrim(to_char(account_number), '0') from accounts   This works but I need HQL

Answer (score 4):

You can use @Formula annotation and introduce a new field - trimmedAccount

```
@Formula("TRIM(REPLACE((account_number), '0', '%')")
private Integer trimmedAccount;
```

Then just use the trimmedAccount in your HQL

Comment: Wouldn't it still be a String? Or would the formula automatically convert the String to an Integer?

Comment: Yes, it should be String. I just needed it and had to make it String for it to work. @Tiya Please mark this answer as the correct answer, even though you solved it for your code another way, it would be nice for others finding this question that this is indeed a correct answer.